# facebook integration Error 2500 OAuthException xcode 8 Swift 3

Tags: swift3, facebook-login, xcode8

I am working on facebook integration in xcode 8 Swift 3.
i have used the following code

```
let parameters = ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"]

    FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).start { (connection, result, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error)
            return
        }
```

But I am getting below error.

> Optional(Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=An active access token must be used to query information about the current user., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=2500, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
>       body =     {
>           error =         {
>               code = 2500;
>               "fbtrace_id" = "FmK/8QACfhe";
>               message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
>               type = OAuthException;
>           };
>       };
>       code = 400;
>       }})
>   can anyone help me out this ??

Comment: try this, FBSession.activeSession = fbSession.

Comment: its not setting up in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    print("Login buttoon clicked")

```
let graphRequest:FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"first_name, gender, last_name, email, picture.type(large)"])

graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

    if ((error) != nil)
    {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
    else
    {
            let data:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]
            print(data["first_name"]!)
            print(data["last_name"]!)
            print(data["email"]!)
            print(data["id"]!)
            print(data["gender"]!)
        }
})
```

}